# How to resolve "chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH" error when running Selenium Chrome using virtualenv within PyDev?

Tags: python, selenium, virtualenv, pydev, selenium-chromedriver

Short:

Having read **Controlling the Browser with the selenium Module** at https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11, I am trying to run the Selenium Chrome driver in a virtual environment from PyDev.  I have managed to do it from outside PyDev, but from within, I get:

> `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Long:

I'm using Linux Debian 3.10.11-1.

Following https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/, before even starting with PyDev, I . . .

1. Set up a virtual environment with virtualenv

   1. Installed virtualenv

      ```
      pip install virtualenv
      ```
   2. Made a directory for my project

      ```
      cd ~/temp/
      ```

      ```
      mkdir my_project
      ```

      ```
      cd my_mproject
      ```
   3. Created a virtual environment called `env`

      ```
      virtualenv env
      ```
   4. Activated it.

      ```
      source env/bin/activate
      ```
   5. Went into Python's interactive mode to tell myself which version of Python I was using

      ```
      python
      ```

      ```
      Python 2.7.12rc1 (default, Jun 13 2016, 09:20:59) 
      [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
      ```
2. Exited out of the interacive mode and installed the Selenium stuff

   1. First the module

      ```
      pip install selenium
      ```
   2. Following suggestion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/obey-the-testing-goat-book/Ty4FQoV3S0Q, installed chromedriver

      1. ```
         cd env/bin/
         ```
      2. ```
         wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.22/chromedriver_linux64.zip
         ```
      3. ```
         unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
         ```
3. Wrote a little script to see if it would work

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   ```

   Ran it.  A Chrome web-browser window opened.  Great.

Now to try it in PyDev:

Roughly following https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/08/31/getting-started-using-python-eclipse/ . . .

1. Installed Eclipse (Neon)
2. Installed PyDev
3. From within Eclipse, created a new project (**File** menu > **New Project** > **General** > **Project**, entered a **Project Name** and clicked **Finish**).
4. Back at the command prompt (because I haven't yet found out how to do this from within Eclipse and PyDev): `cd`'ed into my new project's root directory and created a virtual environment.
5. As before, still at the command prompt, I activated the new project's virtual environment and installed the Selenium module and then the `chromedriver` executable file that came up of the `chromedriver_linux64.zip` file.
6. Back in Eclipse, I signed up my project to use the virtual environment, which I guess in PyDev lingo is called not a virtual environment, but rather an interpreter:

   1. **Window** menu > **Preferences** > **PyDev** > **Interpreters** > **Python Interpreters** > **Add**.
   2. Gave the interpreter a name.
   3. For **Interpreter Executable**, I selected the `python2.7` file in my project's virtual environment's `bin` directory
   4. Right-clicked on my project, select **Properties**  > **PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar** > Under **Interpreter** selected my new interpreter > **OK**.
7. Gave my project the same script . . .

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   ```

   and ran it by clicking on the **Run** menu > **Run As** > **Python Run**.

   Now, though, instead of a Chrome web-browser window opening, I get only a message in Eclipse's console:

   > `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

To get the web browser window to open as it does when I run the same scrip from a command prompt, I have tried:

- adding the the virtual environment's `bin` folder (because that's where the `chromedriver` file is) to the interpreter.
- deleting the interpreter and creating it new.
- copying the `chromedriver` into the same directory where my script is.  No difference.
- adding the `chromedriver_linux64.zip` file that I downloaded to the interpreter.  Still the same error.

I been continuing by writing my script in PyDev, then turning to the command prompt to run it.  Just wish I could run it in PyDev's debug mode.

How can I get this 'chromedriver' in the "`PATH`" in PyDev so I can run the script from Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best thing to do, but I have found something that seems to work: I have added to my interpreter the already available variable named PATH, and I have edited that variable's value to include the relative path to my project's virtual environment's `bin` directory (ie, the directory where I have the `chromedriver` executable file saved).

More precisely:

1. **Window** menu in Eclipse > **Preferences** > **PyDev** on the left > **Interpreters** > **Python Interpreters**.
2. Selected the interpreter that I had created earlier for my project (as descibed in the question above)
3. Switched from **Libaries** to **Environment** in the bottom half of the **Preferences** window
4. Clicked on the **Select...** button on the right.

   A list of **Environment Variable** appeared.
5. Scrolled down through the list and found one named **PATH**.  Selected it and click on the **OK** button.

   It and its value (`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`) appeared in the otherwise empty list.
6. I selected it and clicked on **Edit...**

   Its name and value became editable.
7. To the right-hand end of the value I added `:env/bin` (ie, the relative path from the directory holding my script to my project's virtual environment's `bin` directory).
8. Clicked **OK** to get back to the **Preferences** window > **Apply** in the **Preferences** window > **OK** to close the **Preferences** window.
9. Ran the program from within Eclipse (selected the script file > **Run** menu > **Run As** > **Python Run**).

A Chrome (well, Chromium - this is Debian) window opened just as had been happening when I was running my program from the command prompt.

Great.

Comment: Steps 1 to 3 worked for me, then in Python Interpreters, in Environment, I could click New, create a variable: E.g. "chromedriver", with a value: "/usr/local/bin" and then click Apply & OK. To be more clear on the value path, you can check where ChromeDrive is on your system. On a Mac this can usually be found in "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver".

Answer (score 1):

If all attempts to put chromedriver in your PATH fail, you can also hand the executable path to webdriver.Chrome() like so:

```
chromedriver_loc = '/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_loc)
```

This was my eventual solution when trying to run chromedriver from a virtualenv.