# "Open Browser" command not working for robot framework in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, macos-mojave

I am new to Robotframework and wrote my first selenium test and ecountered a problem where I am unable to open browser using "Open Browser" command of robot framework. It gives me error "chromedrvier executable needs to be in PATH". I have chromedriver in PATH and I am able to run chromdriver using terminal without having to navigate to bin folder.

**The Code that gives me error:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary


*** Test Cases ***

SeleniumTestCase

    Open Browser        https://www.google.com     chrome    
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    name=q    
    Input Text     name=q    weRplay
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    name=btnK    
    Click Button    name=btnK    
    Sleep    3
    Close All Browsers
```

**The code that works for me:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary


*** Test Cases ***

SeleniumTestCase
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver 
    Go To    https://www.google.com
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    name=q    
    Input Text     name=q    weRplay
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    name=btnK    
    Click Button    name=btnK    
    Sleep    3
    Close All Browsers
```

I am using following tools:

- MacOS Mojave
- Eclipse 2019
- Red
- Robotframework
- Robotframework
- Seleniumlibrary

Comment: Have a look here for an answer...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173541/how-to-resolve-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-error-when-running

Answer (score 0):

Put ChromeDriver.exe in the Python folder in C:\....., restart RED or Eclipse.
If you wrote like this it should work

```
Open Browser http://www.random.com  ie
```